# How best to format a returned object

Tags: object, underscore.js

I'm currently returning a set of objects from a database as follows:

```
 function returnedData () {
    query.find({
      success: function(results) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
       var object = results[i];
       var title = object.get('Title');
       var summary = object.get('Summary');
       var html = '<p>' + title + '</p>';
     }
    }
 });
}
```

This works fine if I output it doing the following:

```
$('.results').append(html);
```

However, I would like the returned object returned in such a fashion that I can use underscore.js to insert the data correctly etc

```
var listOfContacts = [
 {
  title: title,
  summary: summary
 },
 {
  title: title2,
  summary: summary2
 }
];
```

Is there any way that the returned data can be formatted in such a way?

Comment: I "get" may be a parse thing. Having object.title returns undefined. However, .get works fine and references the database column information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something more complicated than this?

```
results.map(object => ({title: object.get('Title'), summary: object.get('Summary')}))
```

Old-fashioned way:

```
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
  var object = results[i]; 
  var Title = object.get('Title'); 
  var Summary = object.get('Summary'); 
  result.push({ title: Title, summary: Summary });
}
```

Comment: I got it working with the following. However, it only returns the last meet item. Any reason for that? There are about 10 items in the database but only the latest is returned.                 for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {        
        var object = results[i];
        var Title = object.get('Title');
        var Summary = object.get('Summary');
        var object = [
          {
            title:Title,
            summary:Summary
          }
        ];

Comment: You are overwriting `object` each time through the loop. Try pushing to it instead.

Comment: Hi Torazaburo - Are you able to help with the syntax please? Thanks for responding.

Comment: Dude, that's amazing. Thank you.